# Add restriction in WebView to block other links open in WebView

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have some problems with WebView, I have a WebView that calls the
google class, but I have a problem because through the google class a
person can access other links, I was wondering if you can add
restriction in WebView to block other links open in WebView.

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <WebView
          style={styles.webview}
          setSupportMultipleWindows={false}
          ref={this.WEBVIEW_REF}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          allowsFullscreenVideo={true}
          onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
          source={{
            uri: "https://classroom.google.com",
          }}
          allowFileAccess={{}}
          startInLoadingState={true}
          renderLoading={() => (
            <View style={[styles.containerWebView]}>
              <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#00ff00" />
              <Text style={styles.loadingText}>
                Estamos configurando sua internet patrocinada. Isso pode demorar
                um pouco.
              </Text>
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```